# KineticJS mouseover circle - cursor style

Tags: mouseover, kineticjs, geometry

I am using the following to change the style of the cursor when the mouse is over the circle:

```
            circle1.on('mouseover', function () {
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            });
            circle1.on('mouseout', function () {
                document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            });
```

It works great if I draw the circle using:

```
  var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: 512,
            y: 512,
            radius: 140,
            stroke: '#00ffff',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            opacity: 0.5
        });
```

However if I use:

```
var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
                drawFunc: function (canvas) {
                    var context1 = canvas.getContext();
                    context1.beginPath();
                    context1.arc(512, 512, this.getRadius(), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    context1.lineWidth = this.getStrokeWidth();
                    context1.strokeStyle = this.getStroke();
                    context1.stroke();
                },
                radius: 140,
                stroke: '#00ffff',
                strokeWidth: 15,
                opacity: 0.5
            });
```

It does not work!  The cursor does not change its style; can we just use radius for mouse over.  I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you also need to define "drawHitFunc":

```
circle1.setDrawHitFunc(function (canvas) {
                var context2 = canvas.getContext();
                context2.beginPath();
                context2.arc(100, 100, this.getRadius(), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
               context2.closePath();
                canvas.fillStroke(this);
            });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/4DJdU/1/

Answer (score 0):

no, you just need to correctly structure the drawFunc when creating custom shapes.  Here's an example:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/

The problem is that you're using context.stroke().  You need to use canvas.stroke(this);

Anytime you actually render something, like strokes and fills, you need to use the canvas renderer object because it draws onto both the scene graph (what you see) and a specialized hit graph (used for event detection)

Docs:

http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Canvas.php